# Bot doesn't handle Http request

Tags: c#, api, http, asp.net-core, botframework

I've created Bot using Microsoft Bot Framework and want it to handle http requests.

According to this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) I've created controller, cleared Get method body (left only the return of ContentResult for caller - I want at least handle the request), deployed bot, but keep getting 500 Internal Server Error.

Bot works correctly for typical Bot channels (I am using Teams).

Here is the controller:

```
[Route("api/notify")]
[ApiController]
public class NotifyController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter _adapter;
    private readonly string _appId;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference> _conversationReferences;

    public NotifyController(IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter adapter, IConfiguration configuration, ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference> conversationReferences)
    {
        _adapter = adapter;
        _appId = configuration["MicrosoftAppID"];

    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        return new ContentResult()
        {
            Content = "<html><body><h1>Request has been processed.</h1></body></html>",
            ContentType = "text/html",
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
        };
    }
}
```

Maybe I have to configure something else, so controller will be working?

Comment: When do you get the 500 error? Please include exact steps you take to reproduce the issue. Which part isn't working? Just the `api/notify` endpoint?

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT I deployed bot in my Azure storage, as it is expected in deployment instruction. Then I test it in Teams - it works. Then I try to send http request via Postman to mysite.azurewebsites.net/api/notify

Comment: Your bot and the `api/notify` endpoint works locally? If not, you need to solve that, first. If so, you need to look at your deployed bot's logs. Start with [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-500-errors?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=dotnetwebapi)

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT I tried troubleshooting and got this exception message: _Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2[System.String,Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ConversationReference]' while attempting to activate 'EchoBot.Controllers.NotifyController'._ What can I do to activate controller correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error, it looks like you're missing some dependency injection. Please add this line to your `Startup.cs` > `ConfigureServices()` so that it matches the [Proactive Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages/Startup.cs):

```cs
services.AddSingleton<ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference>>();
```

Note: If this is a new bot, it may be easiest to start with this sample and then build from there.

Comment: Thank you, turned out I had several configuration mistakes. In general, most helpful was the troubleshooting guide